# Checking if User is Subscribed to List of Channels

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

I'm using Parse to push notifications. What I'm trying to do is to send notifications to users who are subscribed to a specific set of channels. The notifications should only send when the user has that entire list of channels subscribed to. Not a subset of those channels.

I tried to use queries and then

```
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", audienceGender);
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", audienceEducation);
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", audienceCity);
```

Buts its sending notifications to users who are subscribed to any one of those channels. Setting channels like so

```
channels.add("male");
```

Produced the same results. Anyway to aggregate a list of strings and then compare them to all the channels the user is subscribed to? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going through documentation (https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) and I think:

```
ArrayList<String> channels = new ArrayList<String>();
channels.add(audienceGender);
channels.add(audienceEducation);
channels.add(audienceCity);
pushQuery.whereContainsAll("channels", channels);
```

should works correctly

Answer (score 2):

Suggested way by Parse to get channel list is:

```
List<String> channels = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels");
```